# redirect a domain extension to a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to create a permanent htaccess redirect (301) from all my domain extensions into the appropriate subdirectories. The "rules" are as follow:

Redirect belgian website to its subdirectory on the main website:

from: `www.example.be`

to: `www.example.com/befr/`

Of course I would like to preserve the url parameters (if any) of the "from". Globaly, if someone entered the first url it should redirect to the second url (langage subdirectory in the main website).

I'm using wordpress and I'm hosting on a plesk I've read many things here but I'm stuck, thank you very much in advance for your help

---

PS: I've tried that but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/befr/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Make sure that rule is at the very top of your htaccess file, what errors are you getting? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Better you copy/paste complete .htaccess in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i've tried many things but the problem came from the DNS configuration. The redirection wasn't catch as such on the ".com" website and the referer remained ".com" instead of ".be" so the rule wasn't triggered. I'ive fixed the DNS configuration and it's all good now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question, your code should be working (with informations you gave).
If it's not, here are some points to check:

**1.** Make sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled and **htaccess** can be executed (Apache config).

**2.** Your htaccess has to be in root folder (where example.**be** is forwarded).

**3.** About your htaccess' code:

- since you're using **Wordpress**, make sure **your rule is on top of other rules**
- don't forget to escape `.` (second one) in `RewriteCond` (otherwise it doesn't mean the same) even if it works that way
- replace `R` flag (302 by default) by `R=301` if you want a 301 redirect

---

Your code now looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/befr/$1 [R=301,L]

# your other rules (and Wordpress' default rule) here
```

Comment: I've tried it and it solved my problem. The problem came from the redirection itself (at the DNS level) so once on the website the visit wasn't considered as refered by example.be but as example.com. I've fixed that and it's now working as it should. Thank you for your answer.